# Div only appears when bootstrap select is open

Tags: javascript

I have two bootstrap select menus. I want a div to be visible to display a help message only when one of them is open. The code I have works fine with normal select menus but not bootstrap select menus. At the moment the div appears when you close one, not when you open one. Can anyone help?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".pickerSelectClass").selectpicker();   

var open = false;
      function isOpen(){
          if(open)
             $('#hidden').show();
          else
             $('#hidden').hide();
      }
      $("button").on("click", function() {
            open = !open;
            isOpen();
      });
      $("button").on("blur", function() {
            if(open){
               open = !open;
               isOpen();
            }
      });
      $(document).keyup(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 27) {
            if(open){
               open = !open;
               console.log(isOpen());
      }}});
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" type = "text/css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.css" type = "text/css"/>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div class="selectContainer" style="float: left;">
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="i_0">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
  
  <select class="form-control pickerSelectClass" id="i_1">
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
  </select>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id='hidden' style="display: none;">
Choose a number
</div>

</body>
```